# Can I dump the current nconf configuration to an object?

Tags: node.js, flatiron.js

Is there any method in `nconf` to collect all the keys from all the stores into a single object?

Imagine I've got this little script:

```
assert = require('assert');
nconf = require('nconf');

nconf.argv().env().defaults({'C': 3});
assert.equal(nconf.get('A'), 1);
assert.equal(nconf.get('B'), 2);
assert.equal(nconf.get('C'), 3);
assert.deepEqual({'A':1, 'B':2, 'C':3}, nconf.X); // <-- What's X?
```

that I run with

```
A=1 node script.js -B 2
```

Is there an `nconf.X` that will pass the test?  I'd even settle for listing all the configured keys.

Comment: It appears from the source that such an operation is not implemented and to implement it would require accessing the Provider's properties and building such a object from the Stores.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes to get the object you can do the following;

```
nconf.get();
```

it will fail the test as argv will with the exec string and env will have a lot more variables though.

You could whitelist the env call using the following

```
nconf.env({whitelist: 'A'});
```

Also the defaults adds a 'type' with value 'literal' to the resulting output.

For a test that passes you could use this;

```
var assert = require('assert'),
nconf = require('nconf');

nconf.argv().env({whitelist: ['A']}).defaults({'C': 3});
assert.equal(nconf.get('A'), 1);
assert.equal(nconf.get('B'), 2);
assert.equal(nconf.get('C'), 3);

var object = nconf.get();

delete object.type;
delete object['$0'];
delete object['_'];

assert.deepEqual({'A':1, 'B':2, 'C':3}, object);
```

Comment: Great, thanks!  If configuration is fixed after startup, does it seem crazy to use that `object` to lookup settings using natural js paths instead of `:` delimited nconf paths?

Comment: Your welcome, I would assume its a matter of preference, I export to an object as I find it more convenient.

Comment: @Jason Brumwell Instead of `nconf.get()`, can I get only the configurations passed in from command line, `process.argv`? Apparently, `nconf.get('argv')` doesn't work.

Comment: I would also like to get all the nconf properties